# Does material on earth exists, that can expand endlessly in the vacuum of the space?

Tags: space-expansion, material-science, vacuum, matter

As far as I have learned, space is a hard vacuum.

Is there any material, that can expand endlessly in space or theoretically would it be possible for a material in future to behave like this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, gas will expand endlessly in space. The only restrictions are that it must start out warm enough so that its molecules have a KE greater than its self-gravitational escape velocity.

Comment: In fact, so will the components of a solid or liquid as they evaporate, albeit this will take longer